# Load images from DB once first 10 have loaded

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm having allot of trouble with my current php code. It loads all 300+ image url's from the database (Which is quick) yet I need 10 images to load once, and once all 10 have loaded, I need it to load another 10. And show a dialog to inform the user that another 10 are on there way.
Here is my sql / PHP Loop:

```html
<?php $results = $con->query("SELECT * FROM media WHERE catagory = 'funday' AND image_format = 'jpg'"); ?>
           <?php while($result = $results->fetch_object()): ?>
        <img src="media/<?=$result->image?>.<?=$result->image_format?>" data-full="media/<?=$result->image?>.<?=$result->image_format?>" class="m-p-g__thumbs-img" />
        <?php endwhile;?>
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is a question and answer site...so what is the question?

Comment: You are asking us to do the code for you. All you are doing is loading 10 images, and have a condition that tells the user another 10 images are loading, wait for them to be loaded and display them and keep doing this on a certain condition (e.g if the user goes to the bottom of the page or clicks a button)

Answer (score 0):

Use `offset`

`SELECT name FROM mydb ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10`

But this will be only one request. If you want to send other picturem you will need javascript on your client side to send some AJAX request to gather the new 10 pictures each time

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for requesting image data on demand, i.e. not fetching all of them at once from your server, your term is "lazy loading images"

Here is some JavaScript for a starting point. It creates an image and informs you when it is loaded to browser:

```js
var myImage = document.createElement("img"); // create an image element
myImage.onload = function() { console.log("loaded"); } // attach its load event
myImage.setAttribute("src", "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/"); // set its source
```